# R gsub numbers and space from variables

Tags: r, gsub

With gsub I am able to remove the `#` from these person variables, however the way I am trying to remove the random number is not correct. I also would like to remove the space after the persons name as well but keep the space in the middle of the name.

```
c('mike smith #99','John johnson #2','jeff johnson #50') -> person

c(1:99) -> numbers

person <- gsub("#", "", person, fixed=TRUE)

# MY ISSUE
person <- gsub(numbers, "", person, fixed=TRUE)

df <- data.frame(PERSON = person)
```

Current Results:

```
PERSON
mike smith 99
John johnson 2
jeff johnson 50
```

Expected Results:

```
PERSON
mike smith
John johnson
jeff johnson
```

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c('mike smith #99','John johnson #2','jeff johnson #50') -> person
sub("\\s+#.*", "", person)
[1] "mike smith"   "John johnson" "jeff johnson"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another pattern as an alternative:

```
> gsub("(\\.*)\\s+#.*", "\\1", person)
[1] "mike smith"   "John johnson" "jeff johnson"
```

In the above regex, `(\\.*)` will match a subgroup of any characters before a space (`\\s+`) following by `#` symbol and following by anything. Then `\\1` indicates that `gsub` should replace all the original string with that subgroup `(\\.*)`

An easier way to get your desired output is :

```
> gsub("\\s+#.*$", "", person)
[1] "mike smith"   "John johnson" "jeff johnson"
```

The above regex `\\s+#.*$` indicates that everything consisting of space (`\\s+`), a `#` symbol and everyting else until the end of string (`\.$`) should be removed.

Using `str_extract_all` from stringr package

```
> library(stringr)
> str_extract_all(person, "[[a-z]]+", simplify = TRUE)
     [,1]   [,2]     
[1,] "mike" "smith"  
[2,] "ohn"  "johnson"
[3,] "jeff" "johnson"
```

Also you can use:

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_all(person, regex="[[a-z]]+", simplify=TRUE)
```

Comment: I went with the gsub option as it was the first I saw, Thank you for the other answers. Could you let us know what the arguments you are referring to in the line above are?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for with 'arguments', in each function calls arguments are explicitly written.

Comment: (\\.*)\\s+#.*   and   \\1

Comment: is there any need of capturing as that will slow down. why not just use `sub("\\s+#.*", "", person)`??

Comment: no need for `gsub`, `sub` is enough, in this example but also in general if you include `$` in your pattern

Comment: @Onyambu Write your comment as an answer please and Ill give you credit

Answer (score 0):

We can create the pattern with `paste`

```
pat <- paste0("\\s*#(", paste(numbers, collapse = "|"), ")")
gsub(pat, "", person)
#[1] "mike smith"   "John johnson" "jeff johnson"
```

---

Note that the above solution was based on creating pattern with 'numbers'.  If it is only to remove the numbers after the `#` including it

```
sub("\\s*#\\d+$", "", person)
#[1] "mike smith"   "John johnson" "jeff johnson"
```

---

Or another option is

```
unlist(strsplit(person, "\\s*#\\d+"))
```

NOTE: All the above are `base R` methods

---

```
library(tidyverse)
data_frame(person) %>% 
      separate(person, into = c("person", "notneeded"), "\\s+#") %>% 
      select(person)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could alternately be done with `read.table`.

```
read.table(text = person, sep = "#", strip.white = TRUE, 
  as.is = TRUE, col.names = "PERSON")
```

giving:

```
        PERSON
1   mike smith
2 John johnson
3 jeff johnson
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that deletes any sequence of non (lowercase) alphabetic characters at the end of the string.

```
gsub("[^a-z]+$", "", person)
[1] "mike smith"   "John johnson" "jeff johnson"
```

If you want to allow for words that are all upper case or end with an uppercase character.

```
gsub("[^a-zA-Z]+$", "", person)
```

Some names might end with `.`:

```
gsub("[^a-zA-Z.]+$", "", person)
```